# Graphical glitch on review

Tags: bug, review-queues

I was reviewing some question on the Suggested Edits queue, rejected one edit and this happened on the new question:

[image]

It seems there's an error but it's not shown properly. I'm using Google Chrome.

Has anybody else encountered this issue?